# Use proxy list with perl script

Tags: perl, proxy

I'm currently working with a single proxy, but I would like to improve my script by adding a proxy list. How can I do that?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use IO::Select;
use HTTP::Response;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
use URI::URL;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use strict
use warnings
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->proxy( 'http', 'http://127.0.0.1:8088' );    # Single Proxy
$tmp="tmp";
    if (-e $tmp) 
    {
    }
    else
    {
        mkdir $tmp or die "Error creating directory: $tmp";
    }
$logo="             
";

print $logo;
print "\t";
print colored("[ CMS DETECTOR ]",'white on_blue'),"\n\n\n";
print colored ("Start At $datetime",'white on_red'),"\n\n";

open(tarrget,"<$ARGV[0]") or die "I need a list \n";
while(<tarrget>){
chomp($_);
$site = $_;
if($site !~ /http:\/\//) { $site = "http://$site/"; };
efrez();
}
sub efrez($site){
$ua->default_header( "Connection" => "keep-alive" );
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");
$ua->timeout (10);

my $efreez = $ua->get("$site")->content;
if($efreez =~/wp-content\/themes\/|wp-content\/plugins\/|wordpress/) {
    print colored("[WORDPRESS] $site",'white on_magenta'),"\n\n\n";
open(save, '>>tmp/wordpress.txt');
    print save "$site\n";
    close(save);
}
elsif($efreez =~/<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"\/media\/system\/js\/mootools.js\"><\/script>|Joomla!|Joomla|joomla/) {
    print colored("[JOOMLA] $site",'white on_magenta'),"\n\n\n";
open(save, '>>tmp/joomla.txt');
    print save "$site\n";   
    close(save);
    }

elsif($efreez =~/\/modules\/system\/system.menus.css|\/sites\/default\/files\/|<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Drupal 7/) {
    print colored("[DRUPAL] $site",'white on_magenta'),"\n\n\n";

open(save, '>>tmp/Drupal.txt'); 
    print save "$site\n";   
    close(save);
    }else{
    print "\n[UNKNOWN] $site\n";
}
}
```

I tried use ***proxified*** but it didn't work.

I need to use 250 to 300 different proxies (the script should change proxy every 30 minutes). I also need some special filter for enabling and disabling proxies in the list; something like ***grey list*** etc.

Is there any mechanism to implement these things?

Comment: Where is your list of proxies coming from? Is it local? If so, you should be able to simply loop your code over the proxy list.

Comment: Also, I inherited [WWW::FreeProxyListsCom](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::FreeProxyListsCom) a while back, that will fetch proxies from http://freeproxylists.com for you automatically.

Comment: To further, you can use [WWW::ProxyChecker](https://metacpan.org/release/WWW-ProxyChecker) to validate the proxies are alive.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, so we can't really help you to add to it. You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. What is *proxified*, and what does *"it didn't work"* mean when you tried to use it? What is *grey list*?

Comment: Are you trying to write some kind of web crawler? Do you need the proxies because the pages you are crawling are blocking you?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to write a kind of crawler, CMS indetifier. I need proxies because some 'security services' report and block my IP.

Comment: @DanielAbbadelliGarcía have you considered using Proxicity.io APIs for this? (https://www.proxicity.io). They check and verify public proxies and serve them for use in an API. You can use it for free or there are paid options as well! They also have a User Agent API if you are interested in that.